Deploying React frontend and FastAPI backend in Kubernetes
Attempting to deploy React + FastAPI application in Kubernetes in a local cluster but having issues routing requests from frontend to backend.
When running both applications locally (non-dockerized) I am able to send requests to backend successfully. When dockerized and running in Kubernetes I get 500 errors.
Deployment/Service yaml for backend:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: smashac-backend
  labels:
    app: smashac-backend
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: smashac-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: smashac-backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: smashac-backend
          image: jhudson1998/smashac-backend:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: smashac-backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: smashac-backend
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
      nodePort: 30001
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.49.2

Deployment/Service yaml for frontend:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: smashac-frontend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: smashac-frontend
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: smashac-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: smashac-frontend
          image: "jhudson1998/smashac-frontend:latest"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: smashac-frontend
spec:
  selector:
    app: smashac-frontend
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 30000
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.49.2


React app has "proxy": "http://localhost:8000" set in package.json and FastAPI backend has the following:
origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

I think my issue is related to my usage of localhost but I'm not familiar with how to communicate between these two services when deployed in the cluster.

The proxy option in package.json only applies to the react-scripts dev server which you wouldn't / shouldn't be running in your deployed image. How are you making requests in your client-side code?

In the client code, localhost is the machine running the browser; in server code, localhost is the current Pod.  In neither case does it seem likely to reach the backend, in the places you're showing it at the end of the question.

@DavidMaze I assumed minikube would expose services on localhost
